# Error while Enable Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework

I tried this tutorial

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

And when I tried following step

enable-migrations -contexttypename SchoolContext

It results as follows

"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your connection string(s) from your web.config file

Comment: <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ContosoUniversity.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: When I changed "connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;" into "connectionString=.;" it worked.